# Typescript-React State: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'State' has no index signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using Typescript and React in mini project. I am new to typescript and learning right now.

So I have this state:

```
type State = {
  field1: string,
  field2: string,
  field3: number,
  field4: string,
}

const SomeFields = ['field1', 'field3'];

class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
   // Default value for above fields
  }

  isValid = () {
    SomeFields.every((key) => {
      return this.state[key].length;
    });
  }
}
```

Here this line `this.state[key].length` throwing error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'State' has no index signature`.

I can understand that need define type for `SomeFields`, but how can I do that?

Comment: `const SomeFields: Array<keyof State>`

Comment: @MU Thanks, this solves the above error, but gives this error `Type error: Object is possibly 'null'.`. May be because some keys are `null` or has `false` value in state.

Comment: I would say this possible null is about state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implicitly tell TypeScript that this is the array of the keys of the state.

```js
const SomeFields: Array<keyof State>
```

This is also improving TS experience as you will get code completion in your editor/IDE when trying to e.g. add an element to `SomeFields` or use `switch` etc.